# How to mock Principal in spring cloud contract tests?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-cloud

In REST controller I have several methods on which I need to create contract test and I don't know how to provide Principal for passing tests.

One of the method in Controller which has Principal in parameters:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
    @GetMapping("/current")
    public Details getCurrent(Principal principal) {
        return houseManager.getById(Principals.getCurrentUserId(principal));
    }
```

I've created base class for tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {Controller.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class, ControllerTestConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Controller.class})
@AutoConfigureStubRunner
public class ControllersWithSecurityBase {
    @Autowired 
    privet Service service;
    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;
    @Mock
    private Principal mockedPrincipal;

    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new Controller(service));
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/") 
                .with(user("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER"))
                .principal(mockedPrincipal)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .defaultRequest(requestBuilder)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
}
```

Contract:

```
Contract.make {
    name("Should find current by principal")
    request {
        method(GET)
        urlPath(".../current")
    }

    response {
        status(200)
    }
}
```

As result of mvn clean install I've got next exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

What I need to do for correct mocking Principal and passing tests?

Comment: `@WithMockUser(...)`

Comment: Zorglube, Coud you please explain it more deeply? Becouse I already tried to annotated it like: @WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = "USER") above setUp method and above class - as result it still not working.

Comment: `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
@RunWith(value = SpringRunner.class)
public class Tests {

@Test
 @WithMockUser(username = "user_test", authorities = "ROLE_USER")
 public void test() {
...
 }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project use Oauth2 security.

So for mocking Principal object in contract tests I've created bean of OAuth2AuthenticationDetails (this class implements Principal interface).

Class configuration with bean OAuth2AuthenticationDetails is:

```
package com.example.config.fakesecurityconfig;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Request;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationDetails;

import java.util.*;

@Configuration
public class OAuth2TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication() {
        return new OAuth2Authentication(getStoredRequest(), getUserAuthentication());
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oAuth2AuthenticationDetails() {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        return new OAuth2AuthenticationDetails(request);
    }

    private OAuth2Request getStoredRequest() {
        Set<String> scope = new HashSet<>();
        scope.add("read");
        scope.add("write");
        return new OAuth2Request(
                Collections.EMPTY_MAP,
                "clientId",
                getGrantedAuthorityCollection(),
                true,
                scope,
                Collections.EMPTY_SET,
                null,
                Collections.EMPTY_SET,
                Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
    }

    private Authentication getUserAuthentication() {
        String credentials = "PROTECTED";
        Authentication authentication = new TestingAuthenticationToken(getPrincipalMap(), credentials, getGrantedAuthorityAsList());
        return new OAuth2Authentication(getStoredRequest(), authentication);
    }

    private Map<String, String> getPrincipalMap() {
        Map<String, String> principalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        principalMap.put("id", "5c49c98d3a0f3a23cd39a720");
        principalMap.put("username", "TestUserName");
        principalMap.put("password", "TestPassword");
        principalMap.put("createdAt", "2018-06-14 10:35:05");
        principalMap.put("userType", "USER");
        principalMap.put("authorities", getGrantedAuthorityCollectionAsMap().toString());
        principalMap.put("accountNonExpired", "true");
        principalMap.put("accountNonLocked", "true");
        principalMap.put("credentialsNonExpired", "true");
        principalMap.put("enabled", "true");
        principalMap.put("uniqueId", "null");
        principalMap.put("uniqueLink", "fc3552f4-0cdf-494d-bc46-9d1e6305400a");
        principalMap.put("uniqueLinkCreatedAt", "2019-09-06 10:44:36");
        principalMap.put("someId", "59b5a82c410df8000a83a1ff");
        principalMap.put("otherId", "59b5a82c410df8000a83a1ff");
        principalMap.put("name", "TestName");
        return principalMap;
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorityCollection() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")
        );
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorityAsList() {
        return new ArrayList<>(getGrantedAuthorityCollection());
    }

    private LinkedHashMap<String, GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorityCollectionAsMap() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, GrantedAuthority> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : getGrantedAuthorityCollection()) {
            map.put("authority", authority);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

As result my base class for contract tests is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {Controller.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class, OAuth2TestConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Controller.class})
@AutoConfigureStubRunner
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class HousesControllersSecuredBase {
    @Autowired
    private Service service;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oAuth2AuthenticationDetails;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void settingUpTests() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(Controller(houseService));
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .build();
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
        oAuth2Authentication.setDetails(oAuth2AuthenticationDetails);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.authentication = 
            RestAssuredMockMvc.principal(oAuth2Authentication);
    }

    @After
    public void ShuttingDownTests() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the base class and rest assured you need to pass a custom argument resolver with the AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver

```
        mockMvc(
                standaloneSetup( controller )
                        .setCustomArgumentResolvers( new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver() )
```

Also you can pass in the plugin that will add the WithMockUser on each test

```
<build>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-replacer-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>target/generated-test-sources/**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <regex>true</regex>
                <regexFlags>
                    <regexFlag>MULTILINE</regexFlag>
                </regexFlags>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>@Test</token>
                        <value>@WithMockUser
@Test</value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Remember to pass WithMockUser as a fully qualified name.

Comment: Hi, Marcin, thanks for your answer. When I add `new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver()` it constructor needed to set ReactiveAdapterRegistry in parametrs. If I create instance of this class and set as parametr - as result getting error cannot resolve method setCustomArgumentResolvers. How can I resolve method`.setCustomArgumentResolvers( new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver())` ?

Comment: Most likely you have a problem with mismatched versions

Comment: Ok, tell me please, what dependencies and versions do I need?

Comment: I'm not shure if I understanded you correctly, BOM it's a parent like this, yes? `<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>`

Comment: Please check out this sample https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer_security/pom.xml

Comment: Marcin, actualy I found my mistake with .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver()). It's a builder, so I added .build() in the end of method and it works. And now I faced with problem: I've getting next exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Principal must not be null. What do I need configure additionaly for resolve problems with Principal and passing the test?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@WithMockUser` in my base test worked for me.

```
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@SpringBootTest 
@WithMockUser //this will ensure a mock user will be injected to all requests
public abstract class BaseTestCloudContract {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(context);
    }
}
```